# as.factor creating a 'other' level in R

Tags: r

I'm converting a character variable in my data frame `df` to factors. One of my character variables (column) looks like this.

```
Age-Range
19-24
25-34
35-45
45-54
55-64
65-74
75+
```

I'm using the following code to convert this Character Column to factors.

```
df <- mutate_if(df, is.character, as.factor)
```

All other columns are fine except the Age_Range one, for which the `summary()` result looks like below.

```
45-54: 1125
55-64: 984
35-44: 664
65-74:579
75+: 309
(Other):342
NA's: 997
```

I'm wondering why I do not see the Age ranges - 19-24 and 25-34. Could someone help me understand why?

Comment: If you could make this reproducible...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `help(summary)`:

> For factors, the frequency of the first `maxsum - 1` most frequent levels is shown, and the less frequent levels are summarized in "(Others)" (resulting in at most `maxsum` frequencies).

So try adjusting the `maxsum` argument upward and you will see more levels in the result. The default is 100. Here's an example using the `attenu` built-in data set:

```
summary(attenu$station, maxsum = 3)
#    117 (Other)    NA's 
#      5     161      16 
summary(attenu$station, maxsum = 7)
#    117    1028     113     112     135 (Other)    NA's 
#      5       4       4       3       3     147      16
```

Comment: Thank you! This makes so much sense now!